# drawing cache returns the same Image

Tags: android

i have problem with frame layout drawing cache.
i capture the video from camera and display it in frame layout.
i want to read this image(s) and send it to another client with TCP or UDP.
now the problem is the cache dosent update and i have the same image (complete black image) always
here is my code:

```
selfImage.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
selfImage.buildDrawingCache();
mainImage = selfImage.getDrawingCache();
Bitmap bmp = mainImage.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888,false);
streamImage.reset();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, streamImage);
Bitmap temp = bmp;
runOnUiThread(new uiInterface(12, temp));
sendVideo(streamImage);
selfImage.destroyDrawingCache();
mainImage.recycle();
selfImage.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

self image is my frame layout!
please help me.
thanks

Comment: it seams like you get rid of any image before its stored in the cache so all you will get is a black null image

Answer (score 2):

I used this code. It works in my case.

`setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
destroyDrawingCache();
return getDrawingCache();`